# Drop unused factor combination in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I wonder if it is possible to plot factor "b" only on panel "2"?
I really appreciate any help!

```
library(tidyverse) 

df <- tibble(
  group = c(1, 2, 1),
  item_name = factor(c("a", "b", "b")),
  value1 = 1:3
)

df %>% ggplot(aes(item_name, value1)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly... Drop "a" only from the right facet panel, keeping it on the left one..

Comment: I might have misunderstood exactly what you're asking, but your question might be phrased more clearly as "I wonder if it is possible to plot factor "b" only on panel "2"?". The current phrasing sounds like there's no issue having factor "b" on Panel 1.

Comment: Sorry, I´ve edited the OP.. thanks!

Comment: ...but perhaps I misunderstood? The answer accepted below is correct as per your original phrasing (in which case, apologies for any confusion!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%  
ggplot(aes(item_name, value1)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~group, scale="free_x")
```

[image]